# Remove Questionmarks

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I have a problem with removing the questionmarks. I don't want them in my SQL-Database.
But my code isn't working, and I don't know where the problems are.

```
function RemoveQMark(sWork: String): String;
begin
  Delete(sWork, 2, 4);
  Delete(sWork, Length, 2);
  Result := sWork;
end;
```

I want to remove the `?` at the first and last position.

Comment: Wat which position you would like to remove the Qmark?

Comment: Delete is known to work. Clearly your code is broken. Since you didn't give any information as to what values you are passing to the function, or what `Length` is we cannot debug the specifics. So, the answer is, `Delete` works, your code does not, if you want us to help, you have to supply real information. How about an SSCCE?

Comment: Please don't ask the question in comments. Please edit the question to include that crucial information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to use `Delete` on the passed in string. Simply use the Delphi `Copy` function to copy all but the first and last characters directly to the result:

```
function RemoveQMark(const sWork: String): String;
begin
  Result := Copy(sWork, 2, Length(sWork) - 2);
end;
```

Using `const` [on string arguments](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29#Constant_Parameters) allows the compiler to generate more efficient code. (Without `const`, the strings reference count is incremented at the start of the function and decremented at the end (within a try...finally block)).

Answer (score 1):

```
function RemoveQMark(sWork: String): String;
begin
  Delete(sWork, 1, 1);
  Delete(sWork, Length(sWork), 1);
  Result := sWork;
end;
```

Comment: Why do you modify the input parameter and assign it then to the result ? Either define that parameter as `var` and make this `procedure` or make that parameter `const` and return the modified string to the result.